# Jquery affecting all elements with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

This is the code in my html file:

```
    <div id="centerBlock">
        <block>
            <site style="padding-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px">
                <img src="./images/site1.png" alt="some_text"/>
            </site>
            <textOnImage style="padding-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px">
                lolol
            </textOnImage>
        </block>

        <block>
            <site style="padding-top: 163px; margin-left: 20px">
                <img src="./images/site1.png" alt="some_text"/>
            </site>
            <textOnImage style="padding-top: 163px; margin-left: 20px">
                lolol
            </textOnImage>
        </block>

    </div>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
$("block").mouseenter(function(){        
    $("site").fadeTo("slow", 0.25);
    $("textOnImage").animate({ 
        opacity: "1"
    }, 600 );
});

$("block").mouseleave(function(){         
    $("site").fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $("textOnImage").animate({ 
        opacity: "0"
    }, 600 );
 });
```

However, when I hover over one of the two block elements they both go down in opacity and when I move my mouse away from it than they both go back to the original state. I've searched for hours, and I'm 100% sure I've been searching the incorrect terms. How do I do them individually?

Comment: because you are not giving any specific divs ids , that selection goes for all

Comment: I'm new to jquery, can you tell me how I would do this?

Comment: this site is pretty fast and has lot of intelligent people , i was about to type answer , but you already got what you are looking for

Comment: It's been fixed. The position: absolute attribute in the css file interfered. Now I have it in the style and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this` to target only the block that triggered the event and then use `.find()` to find the desired element in that specific block.  The way you were doing it before was obviously finding all `site` elements and all `textOnImage` elements in the whole page not only the ones in the block that triggered the event.

```
$("block").mouseenter(function(){        
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find("site").fadeTo("slow", 0.25);
    $this.find("textOnImage").animate({ 
        opacity: "1"
    }, 600 );
});

$("block").mouseleave(function(){         
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find("site").fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $this.find("textOnImage").animate({ 
        opacity: "0"
    }, 600 );
 });
```

Comment: @Ridz , as jfriend posted , this refers to current object or current context. If you do mousenter on block , at that point that this refers to the elements inside that

Comment: Just the same as with the other answers, it will only affect the second 'block' :/

Comment: @Ridz - It works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZLepq/.  If it's not working in your actual page, then there is something else wrong with your code/HTML that you aren't showing us.

Comment: I removed the position absolute attribute in the css file and now it seems to work... Awkward, but thanks all :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to traverse into the structure of the hovered element. You can use `.find()` like this...

```
$("block").mouseenter(function(){        
    $(this).find("site").fadeTo("slow", 0.25);
    $(this).find("textOnImage").animate({ 
        opacity: "1"
    }, 600 );
});

$("block").mouseleave(function(){         
    $(this).find("site").fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $(this).find("textOnImage").animate({ 
        opacity: "0"
    }, 600 );
 });
```

Within an event handler, `this` is a reference to the element to which the handler is bound.

You could have also used `.children()` instead of `.find()` since the targeted elements are only one level deep.

---

Side note, you can use `.hover()`, and pass two functions like this..

```
$("block").hover(function(){        
    $(this).find("site").fadeTo("slow", 0.25);
    $(this).find("textOnImage").animate({ 
        opacity: "1"
    }, 600 );
},
  function(){         
    $(this).find("site").fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $(this).find("textOnImage").animate({ 
        opacity: "0"
    }, 600 );
});
```

You'll probably also want to add some `.stop()` calls before your `fadeTo` and `animate` calls, otherwise when you mouse over and out rapidly, the animations will get backed up in a queue.

Comment: No, I'm sorry but that doesn't work. By using find it'll only affect the second 'block' and by using children nothing will happen...

Comment: @Ridz: What do you mean? Then handlers are bound to `"block"`, not to `"centerBlock"`.

Comment: Thanks for making the code more compact. I was about to look for something that would stop the queue'd animations. But, again, it only affects the second 'block'. By block I mean the element that starts at 163px.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (provide the `this` context to jquery selector to target the specific elements):

```
$("block").mouseenter(function(){        
    $("site", this).fadeTo("slow", 0.25);
    $("textOnImage", this).animate({ 
        opacity: "1"
    }, 600 );
});

$("block").mouseleave(function(){         
    $("site", this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $("textOnImage", this).animate({ 
        opacity: "0"
    }, 600 );
 });
```

Comment: Same as with am not i am's answer, it'll only affect the second 'block'.

Comment: @Ridz: You've just left the same comment on all three answers. Has it occurred to you that since all the answers are effectively the same, that maybe they're the same for a reason? [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PpjSe/) for you to see it working.

Comment: I removed the position absolute attribute in the css file and now it seems to work... Awkward, but thanks all :)